# Запись данных в таблицу

Tags: php, mysqli, таблицы

Мне нужно сделать новую строку в таблице и записать в эту строку два значения que и ans получаемые из https запроса "/zap.php?que=abc и т.д.". С помощью какого кода php можно это сделать и какая тогда должна быть ссылка со значениями?

```
if (isset($_GET['que'])) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO `capbase` (`que`, `ans`) VALUES ('" . $_GET['que'] . "', '1')";
```

Comment: а зачем убрали SELECT  ? теперь и ответ нужно переписывать...
покажите пример ссылки с несколькими параметрами, не с одним, т.е., что в ссылке `/zap.php?que=abc и т.д.` будет вместо *и т.д*.

Comment: Так мне и нужно узнать как задать ссылку с сразу несколькими параметрами и как их записать в таблицу

Comment: в ссылке должны быть оба параметра `que` и `ans` ?

Comment: да, а потом их надо записать в таблицу

Comment: под *записать в эту строку два значения `que` и `ans`* вы подразумеваете, что в ссылке передается одно значение `que` и одно значение `ans` или то, что передается два значения `que` и два значения `ans` ?

Comment: Одно значение que и одно значение ans

Comment: в таком случае ответ правильный

Comment: А по какой ссылке надо перейти, чтобы записать эти два значения?

Comment: ссылка вида `zap.php?que=abc&ans=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Важно!** Никогда не вставляйте полученные параметры без обработки в sql запрос!

По открывшимся подробностям Вам нужна ссылка вида `/zap.php?que=abc&ans=1`
Соответственно дальше Вы записываете полученные данные:

```
if (isset($_GET['que']) && isset($_GET['ans'])) {
  $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table (`que`, `ans`) VALUES (?, ?)";
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param('si', $_GET['que'], $_GET['ans']); //вместо s и i ставите тип полей `que` и `ans`
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
}
```

*Если вы обрабатываете `$_GET['que']` и `$_GET['ans']` перед вставкой в запрос, использовать подготовленный запрос не нужно*.

[Документация по подготавливаемым запросам](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

[Привязка переменных к параметрам подготавливаемого запроса](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Мне нужно одним запросом по ссылке в которой заранее написаны значения для записи ввести сразу два значения в новую строку таблицы. Или так нельзя и надо вставлять каждое значение по отдельности?

Comment: добавил в вопрос. И зачем здесь команда для поиска значения ans в таблице? SELECT ans FROM capbase

Comment: @TheHaines потому что у Вас изначально был запрос на поиск значения(select) ans в таблице capbase, а сейчас Вы вопрос изменили.